# Make force field only affect objects while they are within a specific area

Tags: soft-body, force-fields

I'm trying to emulate an object floating to the surface of a liquid within a soft body simulation using a wind force field, but I have discovered to my dismay that wind force fields don't care about the position of the object and I can't find a way to make them do. Is there a way to make wind fields area-specific that I missed, or a better way to accomplish this sort of effect?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a max distance on the force field, after doing that the force field will only affect the objects if they are within the set distance rather than affecting the whole scene.

[image: Force field distance]